# Russian Chess Federation leaves Europe (ECU) and joins Asia (ACF). What practical difference does this make?

Tags: fide

Russia, which like Turkey is part in Europe and part in Asia, has [formally left the European Chess Union (ECU) and joined the Asian Chess Federation (ACF)](https://www.chess.com/news/view/russia-joins-asian-chess-federation).

I understand that this means that when these two FIDE associate member organisations organise team and individual championships then Russian players (who currently have to be affiliated with some other federation like FIDE) are no longer elligible to play in ECU tournaments and instead can play in ACF tournaments.

What other practical differences does this make to the players and the Russian Chess Federation?

Answer (score 1):

Since the start of the war with Ukraine, Russia has been sanctioned by many European organizations in several fields. Chess is one of the them. Most likely Russian players would not have been allowed to play European chess tournaments in 2023.

With the change of Russia in FIDE from Europe to Asia, most likely, Russian players will not have a problem  playing the Asian chess championship.